# Unmet dependencies when trying to update nodejs - 20.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, nodejs

When I do open my terminal I'm receiving the following warning about my node version:

```
npm does not support Node.js v14.4.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

So, I decided to update my nodejs but I started to receive some errors in my OS;

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnode64 : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is to be installed
 libpython3.10-dev : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is to be installed
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.12-1+focal2) but 3.7.13-1+focal3 is to be installed
 nodejs : Conflicts: nodejs-doc
          Conflicts: npm
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.11 : Depends: libpython3.11-stdlib (= 3.11.0~b1-1+focal1) but 3.11.0~a6-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.11-minimal : Depends: libpython3.11-minimal (= 3.11.0~b1-1+focal1) but 3.11.0~a6-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) but 3.7.12-1+focal2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know why this problem started but I can't find any reference about how to fix this;

I would appreciate a lot any reference to solve it;

Thank you very much in advance,
Leonardo

Comment: did you try `apt --fix-broken install`, as suggested in the messages?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Oooh... I think that it was finally solved after removing the problematic installations sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq [*name*of*the*package*]